# Rails 5: given these three model associations...am I setting up my nested form field correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Ok...am I doing this correctly? Am I setting up the nested form right given these model associations?

(should I include the volunteer_events controller and the volunteer_shift controller code here as well?)

volunteer_event model

```
class VolunteerEvent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :volunteer_default_event
  validates_presence_of :date
  has_many :volunteer_shifts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :resources_volunteer_events, :dependent => :destroy
  validates_associated :volunteer_shifts

  def date_anchor
    self.date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
  end

  # def date
  #   self.date
  # end

  def to_s
    description
  end

  def time_range_s
    return '0-0' if self.volunteer_shifts.length == 0
    my_start_time = self.volunteer_shifts.sort_by(&:start_time).first.start_time
    my_end_time = self.volunteer_shifts.sort_by(&:end_time).last.end_time
    (my_start_time.strftime("%I:%M") + ' - ' + my_end_time.strftime("%I:%M")).gsub( ':00', '' ).gsub( ' 0', ' ').gsub( ' - ', '-' ).gsub(/^0/, "")
  end

  def merge_similar_shifts
    hash = {}
    self.volunteer_shifts.each{|y|
      k = (y.volunteer_task_type_id.to_s || "0") + "-" + (y.description || "")
      hash[k] ||= []
      hash[k] << y
    }
    hash.each{|k, v|
      prev_length = 0
      length = v.length
      while length != prev_length
        v.each{|first|
          v.each{|second|
            next if first.id == second.id
            combine = false
            if ((first.end_time == second.start_time) or (first.start_time == second.end_time)) and (first.slot_number == second.slot_number)
              first.start_time = [first.start_time, second.start_time].min
              first.end_time = [first.end_time, second.end_time].max
              combine = true
            end
            if combine
              first.assignments << second.assignments
              second.destroy
              v.delete(second)
              first.save!
              break
            end
          }
        }
        prev_length = length
        length = v.length
      end
    }
  end

  def copy_to(date, time_shift, copy_for)
    new = self.class.new(self.attributes)
    assigns = []
    new.volunteer_shifts = self.volunteer_shifts.map{|x|
      n = x.class.new(x.attributes); n.time_shift(time_shift);
      if copy_for.include?(n.volunteer_task_type_id)
        x.assignments.select{|x| x.contact_id && (!x.cancelled?)}.each do |y|
          a = y.class.new(y.attributes)
          a.time_shift(time_shift)
          a.call_status_type_id = nil
          a.attendance_type_id = nil
          a.volunteer_shift = n
          assigns << a
        end
      end
      n
    }
    new.resources_volunteer_events = self.resources_volunteer_events.map{|x| x.class.new(x.attributes)}
    new.date = date
    new.resources_volunteer_events.each{|x| x.time_shift(time_shift)}
    conflictors = assigns.select{|x| x.internal_date_hack_value = date; (!x.contact.nil?) && (!x.contact.is_organization) && x.find_overlappers(:for_contact).length > 0}
    if conflictors.length == 0
      new.save!
      new.volunteer_shifts.each{|x| x.save!}
      assigns.each{|x| x.save!}
      return new
    else
      new.destroy if new.id
      return conflictors
    end
  end
end
```

volunteer_shift model

```
class VolunteerShift < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :roster_id
  validates_presence_of :end_time
  validates_presence_of :start_time
  belongs_to :volunteer_default_shift

  belongs_to :volunteer_task_type
  has_many :assignments
  belongs_to :program
  belongs_to :roster
  belongs_to :volunteer_event

  has_many :contact_volunteer_task_type_counts, :primary_key => 'volunteer_task_type_id', :foreign_key => 'volunteer_task_type_id' #:through => :volunteer_task_type

...
end
```

assignment model

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :volunteer_shift #,:contact_id ???
  belongs_to :volunteer_shift
  has_one :volunteer_task_type, :through => :volunteer_shift, :source => :volunteer_task_type
  belongs_to :contact ,optional: true
  validates_presence_of :volunteer_shift
  validates_associated :volunteer_shift
  belongs_to :attendance_type
  belongs_to :call_status_type
  validates_presence_of :set_date, :if => :volshift_stuck
  # validates_existence_of :contact, :allow_nil => true <----THIS IS BAD NEIBER
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :volunteer_shift, allow_destroy: true

  #fixme: Nodule::DelegationError -
  # This error appears when trying to show the "Add New Assignment" model on the /assignments view
  delegate :set_date, :set_date=, :to => :volunteer_shift
  delegate :set_description, :set_description=, :to => :volunteer_shift

  scope :date_range, lambda { |range|
    joins(volunteer_shift: :volunteer_event)
        .where(volunteer_shifts: { volunteer_events: { date: range } })
  }
  scope :is_after_today, lambda {||
    { :conditions => ['(SELECT date FROM volunteer_events WHERE id = (SELECT volunteer_event_id FROM volunteer_shifts WHERE id = assignments.volunteer_shift_id)) > ?', Date.today] }
  }
  scope :on_or_after_today, lambda {||
    { :conditions => ['(SELECT date FROM volunteer_events WHERE id = (SELECT volunteer_event_id FROM volunteer_shifts WHERE id = assignments.volunteer_shift_id)) >= ?', Date.today] }
  }
  scope :not_cancelled, -> { where('(attendance_type_id IS NULL OR attendance_type_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM attendance_types WHERE cancelled = \'t\'))')}
  scope :roster_is_limited_by_program, -> {where("roster_id IN (SELECT id FROM rosters WHERE limit_shift_signup_by_program = 't')").joins(:volunteer_shift)}

  attr_accessor :attendance_type_id

...
end
```

assignments_controller

```
class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_assignment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token #TODO refactor this line to be very specific

  # GET /assignments or /assignments.json
  def index
    # @assignments = Assignment.limit(20)
    # @assignments = Assignment.where(start: params[:start]..params[:end])
    @assignments = Assignment.date_range(params[:start]..params[:end])

  end

  # GET /assignments/1 or /assignments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /assignments/new
  def new
    @assignment = Assignment.new
    #fixme: build goes here
    @assignment.volunteer_shift.build
    @my_url = {:action => "create", :id => params[:id]}

  end

  # GET /assignments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /assignments or /assignments.json
  def create
    @assignment = Assignment.new(assignment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @assignment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @assignment, notice: "Assignment was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @assignment }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @assignment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  # PATCH/PUT /assignments/1 or /assignments/1.json
  def update

    @assignment.update(assignment_params)
  end

  # DELETE /assignments/1 or /assignments/1.json
  def destroy
    @assignment.destroy
    # NOTE: comment original out 4 now
    # respond_to do |format|
    #   format.html { redirect_to assignments_url, notice: "Assignment was successfully destroyed." }
    #   format.json { head :no_content }
    # end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_assignment
      @assignment = Assignment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def assignment_params
      #fixme: ,volunteer_shift_attributes: [:???, :???, :???] <--- insert this below?
      params.require(:assignment).permit(:title,
        :redirect_to, :set_date, :date_range, :contact_id,
        :start_time, :end_time, :start, :end, :attendance_type_id, :notes,
        :call_status_type_id, :closed, :lock_version, :color,
         volunteer_shift_attributes: [:volunteer_task_type_id,:roster_id,:program_id,:set_description,:set_date,:id,:destroy])
    end
end
```

views/assignment/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @assignment, :url => @my_url, remote: true do |f| %>
...

          <%= f.fields_for :volunteer_shift do |builder| %>
            <%= render 'volunteer_shift_fields', vs: builder %> <=====NESTED FORM THINGIE HERE...
          <% end %>
...
<% end %>
```

_volunteer_shift_fields.html.erb  <--- nested form partial

```
<div class="name large flex-row">
  <%= vs.label :volunteer_shift %>
</div>
<div id="volunteer_shift" class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 p-2">
    <div id="volunteer_shift" class="text-right">
      <!-- old if: if class is assignment show volunteer shift else show default shift -->
      <!--  we need default shift here...NO assignment is attached-->
      <div class="field">
        <%= vs.label :volunteer_task_type_id %>
        <%= select_tag 'volunteer_task_type_id', options_from_collection_for_select([VolunteerTaskType.new(:description => ""),  VolunteerTaskType.instantiables.effective_on(Date.today)].flatten, "id", "description")  %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= vs.label :roster_id %>
        <%= select_tag 'roster_id', options_from_collection_for_select([Roster.new(:name => ""), Roster.all].flatten, "id", "name") %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= vs.label :program_id %>
        <%= select_tag 'program_id', options_from_collection_for_select([Program.new(:name => ""), Program.where(:volunteer => true)].flatten, "id", "name")%>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= vs.label :set_description %>
        <%= vs.text_field(:set_description, nil) %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= vs.label :set_date, "Date" %> <
        <%= vs.text_field(:set_date, nil) %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: someone just came by and voted this down without saying what is wrong with it? i would appreciate a little direction.

Comment: @thefonse your code seems correct. are you facing any issues with saving data with this code?

Comment: @SachinSingh more like displaying my data. these changes have "broken" my assignments/index.json.jbuilder which I use to display on my main page.....here is my SO post....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69867656/rails5-recently-changed-my-form-into-a-nested-form-and-now-need-to-access-the-a